# How I check that an api call to an appengine instance came from a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, frontend, backend

We are using a Google Compute Engine instance to generate convert datastore tables into large downloadable csv files.  We want this instance to log errors to an app engine front end instance by calling:

`/api/log`

But we want to be sure that this call came from the Google Compute Engine instance which has the authority to write to the log.  How can we check that an api call came from a Google Compute Engine instance?

Comment: I know that scheduled tasks work by sending HTTP request to the front end instance, which is similar to what you want to do. In this context of scheduled task, Google App Engine adds a specific HTTP header to allow the front end instance to identify that it comes from a scheduled task (See here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_Securing_URLs_for_cron). With a little research, maybe you can design a similar system? However, if your log API should not be public, why is it accessible on the front end instance?

Comment: Thanks Romain, I'll look into it.  To clarify the log should be accessible to logged in users, just not the open web.

Comment: Then maybe you could try using `login: admin` in your `app.yaml` file to restrict access to admins only? See here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status.

Comment: Romain, if I set login: admin will the backend still have access?

Comment: I'm not too sure about that, that's why I said *should try*. It seems to be working like that for `cron` scheduled tasks, but I don't know for backend instances...

Comment: Hello all, I work with Ben. I know that cron runs with administrator rights, so `login: admin` is a good solution. However, our "backend" is a Google Compute Engine instance and thus outside of App Engine. Also, setting `login: required` would make it a pain.

Comment: @Chris glad you've clarified the "backend", i thought he's referring to backend instances

Comment: @RonnieBeltran I did not realize there was a difference, I've updated the question referring to Google Compute Engine instances instead.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how secure you want it to be. The simplest solution is to include a parameter in your POST request that only your backend and front-end instances would recognize - any random sequence of characters will do the trick. The next level is to use a secret key to encrypt the contents of the request - there are many implementations depending on the language that you use.

This approach is more flexible too, if you decide, for example, to move your backend from App Engine to Compute Engine.

Comment: We are using the secret key approach, I was just hoping there would be another solution equal easy to implement but more secure.  I suspect that Google already has a mechanism built in so that instances can identify themselves to one another.

Comment: The problem with Google's internal solution is that they can change it at any time - change headers, routing, IP addresses, etc. - without a warning.

Comment: Fair warning, but I'm pretty sunk into the App Engine way of doing things, they've been stable so far and I do not intend to try and migrate.

Comment: We are using appengine also and using the secret key approach from compute engine to do some long running tasks that would be too expensive to do on appengine, however if i understood correctly that your goal is to generate or convert datastore entities to csv files why not use appengine to do the conversion? you can deploy an app version that has only purpose to do convertions.